# Why it printing last element

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying this javascript code

```
var txt = "", txtLen = 0, elem='';
var speed=90;

function write( obj ) {
    txt = obj.str;
    speed = obj.speed;
    elem = obj.elem;
    txtLen = txt.length;
    setTimeout("loop()", 300);
}
var c=0;
function loop() {
if( c <= txtLen ){
    document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML+=txt.charAt(c);
    c++;
    setTimeout("loop()", speed);
} else {
    c=0;
  }
}
```

but in html when i call **write** function two time its prints only last one, like this-

```
<font id="o"></font><br>
<font id="oo"></font>
<script>
write({ 
 elem:'o', 
 speed:90,
 str:'Hello'
});
write({
 elem:'oo',
 speed:90,
 str:'World'
});

</script>
```

Can anyone tell me please, where the error is??

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`. Just use `setTimeout(loop, 300);`

Comment: The `loop()` function is using global variables to keep track of what string it is processing and what character it is up to. If you call `write()` twice, the second call will be using those *same* global variables.

Comment: `write` waits 300ms before starting to output. By then, the next call to `write` has changed the `txt` and `txtLen` variables to a different value.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't use the [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) tag, it's obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are executing the printing asyncronously, so when you print the first one, the second one already modified your vars.

What you are facing is called impure functions.

> ### Impure functions
>
> All of them which modifies its external
>   environment, usually called **side effect**.
>
> Any function that uses a non-local variable is potentially impure, for example:
>
> function impure(x) { return x + a; }

The idea to solve it is transform your impure functions into pure functions. What does it mean? A pure function is a function which does not modify its external enviromnent.

> ### Pure functions
>
> All of them which does not modify its external
>   environment, for example:
>
> function pure(x, a) { return x + a; }

Below you have your example working:

```html
<font id="o"></font>
<br>
<font id="oo"></font>
<script>
  function write( obj ) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        loop(obj, 0);
      }, 300);
  }

  function loop(obj, c) {
    if( c <= obj.str.length ){
        document.getElementById(obj.elem).innerHTML += obj.str.charAt(c);
        setTimeout(() => {
          loop(obj, c + 1);
        }, obj.speed);
    }
  }
  
  write({ 
   elem:'o', 
   speed:90,
   str:'Hello'
  });
  
  write({
   elem:'oo',
   speed:90,
   str:'World'
  });

</script>
```

As you see, `loop` function takes nothing from its external environment any more.
Sharing vars is not a good option when you are working asyncronously.

Hope It helps you.

Comment: any other way to use this logic

Comment: It should be just an error in the code due some typed mistake. As soon as I can I will fix it, just give.me some time.

Comment: hey, dont waste your time, its worked fine now, thnx

Comment: Hey, I've fixed the code. It was just a remaning parenthesis. If it was helpful, accept the answer and vote it up please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
function loop(obj, c) {
    if( c <= obj.str.length ){
       document.getElementById(obj.elem).innerHTML += obj.str.charAt(c);
       setTimeout(loop, obj.speed, obj,c+1);
    } 
}
function write( obj ) {
    setTimeout( loop,  300, obj, 0);
}
```

The setTimeout function optionally can take variables that will be passed to the callback function